# Would nuclear-heated "hot air" balloon probe be viable for gas giants?

Tags: aerobot

A small Pu-238 core with radiator inside the "skirt" to provide sustained heated atmospheric hydrogen supply to the envelope (plus some thermocouples to produce electricity to power the probe), actual scientific payload hanging on a tether long enough that the core radiation wouldn't disturb it.

Could it work? Would it be possible to build a balloon with enough buoyancy that hydrogen heated with a nuclear core could let it stay afloat in a gas giant atmosphere - break even between mass of heat production structure and buoyant volume? Or are there other problems I missed that would make it impossible?

Note: the question this one was marked as duplicate of, only contains suggestions of "Solar Montgolfier" balloons, heated with sunlight or planet radiation. A linked paper claims these are capable of flight only during the day. Not a problem on a rocky planet where they'd just spend the night on the ground, but not acceptable on a gas giant!

Comment: You mean apart from 'landing' the thing in the atmosphere? Too stormy I guess. The winds on our gas giants have strong up/downdraft motions, so there'd need to be some technology developed to cope with that.

Comment: @gerrit: there's no mention of nuclear power anywhere around these. In particular, they mention solar-powered balloons, which float *only during the day*.